# Get Intent information

Tags: java, android

In a app I bought that is written in Java for Android, I have one line of code that is:

```
data_trip = (HashMap<String, String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("TRIP_DATA");
```

And data_trip variable is filled with a lot of data that is stored in a database in a server. Now I added a field in that database, and is not automatically get. If I do data_trip.get("new_field") I get and error. So somewhere it must be a explicit sql query for doing this. I tried debugging and follow step by step but I can't get anything. The only clue is that line. So, how can I access to that intent and "TRIP_DATA" thing? Im lost.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You would have to start by finding where the Intent is set for that Activity. After you've found that you can likely find the code that is associated with creating that intent. The SerializableExtra is similar to setting Arguments for a Fragment so I'm willing to bet that if you find where the SerializableExtras are set at you can figure out what to add/remove to fix your issue.

Feel free to let me know if you have any further issues or what I have suggested doesn't work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19644948)

Comment: @ice1000 It's an answer, it may not answer the question but it is an answer.

Comment: This is definitely an answer.